# Symfony 3 doesn't display error and disconnected server

Tags: php, symfony

I created first project and I forgot the semicolon. I refresh page but server became disconnect. I run server by console *`php bin.console -v server:run`*
I try add to file `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 'on');`

So... How can I display error and why server is disconnect when find error?
I have php 5.5.12 and xDebug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to run your built in server in a dev mode:

```
php bin/console server:run --env=dev
```

Symfony will now display the errors. Else you can also check the errors in the logs (var/logs/dev.log if you're running in dev mode or var/logs/prod.log if you're running in prod mode)